# Return random post from Google Custom Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

I'm working with a friend who is using the free Google Custom Search on his site. He has a widget which searches through a list of network-member blogs (on various platforms) and then returns the results. I'm wondering if there's a way to add a button - using jQuery or JavaScript - which will perform a search with a random term.

[This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210454/submit-google-custom-search-with-jquery) seems plausible through creating a second action button which adds a random term from an array of popular tags or topics, but it seems like there should be something more straightforward.

The point being that people can go to the search engine, click on "Random Post" have have some articles returned for inspiration, etc. From what I can tell, the Google Search API (now deprecated) could have done that fairly easily. I can't seem to find anyone trying to do something similar using a custom search and I'd appreciate a little direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is included in the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) :
Use the `execute()` method of the element object returned by  `google.search.cse.element.getElement()`

```js
var queries = ['custom search', 'random', 'google', 'Brian Bennett'];
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var cseElement = google.search.cse.element.getElement('standard0');
      var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * queries.length);
      cseElement.execute( queries[rand] );
      }, false );
```

```html
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '011833858776650720395:4l5dii3zv2w';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
<button>Random search</button>
```

Comment: Because I'm learning, I don't see a major difference in your implementation and the one I posted below. Is it better - in general - to use the API methods to run the search? In other words, why is this answer better than the solution I came up with?

Comment: Because it's the way Google recommends, because it doesn't change your actual location as does yours, and because if one day, Google decides to change how it handles those request (e.g if they block direct access to the page you're transferring your user), you will have to rewrite again your code. That said, it's up to you to choose which solution does fit the best your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very elegant, but I ended up solving this problem by setting an array of search terms and then filling in the Google custom search field with a custom search button.

Using [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210454/submit-google-custom-search-with-jquery) as a model, I set up my HTML with a new button in addition to the custom search HTML.

```
<form id="cse-search-box" action="http://google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-2789521296837340:9402765321" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
  <input type="text" name="q" size="31" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
  <!-- This is the new button - the "random" ID allows it to be targeted separately. -->
  <input id="random" type="submit" name="random" value="Random" />
</form>
```

Now that the form is set up, we need to add an array of possible search terms as well as a function to randomly select a topic from the array.

```
// With input selected, do this on click
$( "input#random" ).on('click', function() {

  // The array of possible search terms.
  var myArray = ['animals','dogs','cats', 'emu','fish','snakes', 'panda bears','meerkats','spiders','birds'];

  // Choose a term randomly
  var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

  // Write them term in the search box and then submit the search
  var input = $("input[name='q']");
  input.val(input.val() + ' ' + rand);

  $( "form#cse-search-box" ).submit();
});
```

Obviously, the larger the array, the better randomness you'll get. One thing I would like to improve is to programmatically create the array by reading the RSS feeds of the blogs and sites this is searching through. This will work for now, though.